# Consume Web Service HTTPS (with certificate for authentication)

Tags: c#, web-services, windows-mobile, ssl-certificate, x509certificate

I am trying to consume a Web Service HTTPS (using a certificate authentication). I have added my Web Service in my Web Reference on my project and "myCertificate.cer" has imported to Console Root\Certificates\Personal.

I have an error 401: The request failed with HTTP status 401: Unauthorized.

Any idea?

```
....
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
...
string certPath = @"C:\myCertificate.cer";

// Load the certificate into an X509Certificate object.
X509Certificate cert = X509Certificate.CreateFromCertFile(certPath);

// Create an instance of the Web service proxy.
zgetuser_certificate mathservice = new zgetuser_certificate();

// Create an X509Certificate object
mathservice.ClientCertificates.Add(X509Certificate.CreateFromCertFile(certPath));

try
{
    ZgetUser user = new ZgetUser();
    user.Username = "USER01";

    ZgetUserResponse response = new ZgetUserResponse();
    response = mathservice.ZgetUser(user); //ERROR: The request failed with HTTP status 401: Unauthorized.

    Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}, {2}, {3}", response.Company, response.Firstname, response.Fullname, response.Lastname);
}

catch (Exception ex)
{
    if (ex is WebException)
    {
        WebException we = ex as WebException;
        WebResponse webResponse = we.Response;
        throw new Exception("Exception calling method. " + ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Sorry for my English. Thanks!!!

Comment: Take a look at the [ServicePointManager.CertificatePolicy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.certificatepolicy%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) property and the [ICertificatePolicy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.icertificatepolicy%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) interface.