# Working with WEB API Authentication in .net Compact Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, windows-mobile, compact-framework, windows-ce

We have an application that uses a REST service from our customer through XML requests and responses. It runs on a Motorola (now Zebra) MC3190 Handheld Computer running Windows CE 6.0.

Last week they decided to publish the service using HTTPS and since then my application stopped being able to use the service. I can't even get pass the login.

Now, I've already tried to install on the device all the certificates available from their HTTPS URL and also [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17029815/4229024); but none of it worked.

The strangest thing is that when running the same application on a Desktop environment (Windows 10, for example), everything works like a charm.

I've already ran out of ideas of what to do, and I hope you guys can give me something to work with.

Answer (score 1):

I assume the HTTPS site uses a SHA2 certificate (most, if not all, do these days).

Our experience is that Windows CE only supports SHA1 certificates ([details here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32986714/wince-6-smart-device-could-not-establish-secure-channel-for-ssl-tls-error/32988149#32988149)), so that might be the issue.